# PHP, averaging numbers in a loop

Tags: php, html, forms, math, html-table

I currently have a loop within a table that outputs 8 formulated values as one table row that spans the 8 columns. This is a screenshot of it:

[image]

It's great the way it is, except for that last column cell for corrected accuracy under 'Overall'. This needs to be the average of the 8 preceding values (obviously, one is 0 or NAN).

Here is the code that creates that last row:

```
        <tr>
        <td style="border:none; text-align: left;">Meter Volume: </td>
        <td><? echo $row['test1MeterVol'];?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><? echo $row['test2MeterVol'];?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><? echo $row['test3MeterVol'];?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><? echo $row['test4MeterVol'];?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><? echo $row['test5MeterVol'];?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><? echo $row['test6MeterVol'];?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><? echo $row['test7MeterVol'];?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><? echo $row['test8MeterVol'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border:none; text-align: left;">Tester Volume: </td>
        <td><? echo $row['test1TesterVol'];?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><? echo $row['test2TesterVol'];?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><? echo $row['test3TesterVol'];?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><? echo $row['test4TesterVol'];?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><? echo $row['test5TesterVol'];?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><? echo $row['test6TesterVol'];?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><? echo $row['test7TesterVol'];?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><? echo $row['test8TesterVol'];?>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border:none; text-align: left;">Tester Accuracy: </td>
        <td><? echo $row['test1Accuracy'];?>%&nbsp;</td>
        <td><? echo $row['test2Accuracy'];?>%&nbsp;</td>
        <td><? echo $row['test3Accuracy'];?>%&nbsp;</td>
        <td><? echo $row['test4Accuracy'];?>%&nbsp;</td>
        <td><? echo $row['test5Accuracy'];?>%&nbsp;</td>
        <td><? echo $row['test6Accuracy'];?>%&nbsp;</td>
        <td><? echo $row['test7Accuracy'];?>%&nbsp;</td>
        <td><? echo $row['test8Accuracy'];?>%&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="border:none;">Overall</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td style="border:none; text-align: left;">Corrected Accuracy: </td>

/*This is the loop that builds the formula for all 8 tests*/

        <?php for($i=1; $i<=8; $i++){ 
            $testFormA = $row["test".$i."MeterVol"] / $row["test".$i."TesterVol"]; 
            $testFormB = $testFormA * $row["test".$i."Accuracy"]; 
            $testFinalForm = $testFormB / 100;                                      
        ?>
        <td><?php echo round($testFinalForm,3) ?>%</td>


        <?php }?>
```

Since these 8 values are gathered in a loop and put out in one row, is there a way to put the average of them in that last cell?

Update:

```
var_dump($row["test".$i."MeterVol"]  );
var_dump($row["test".$i."TesterVol"]);

string(4) "0.61" string(4) "0.62" string(4) "0.98" string(1) "1" string(4) "2.41" string(4) "2.44" string(4) "8.87" string(4) "9.03" string(4) "6.65" string(4) "6.72" string(5) "26.12" string(4) "26.5" string(5) "52.45" string(4) "52.6" string(1) "0" string(1) "0"
```

Comment: Can you update your question to the raw array format for `$row`?

Comment: Do you mean as a var_dump? Sorry, I'm confused on how to do exactly what you're asking

Comment: Yeah, `var_dump($row)` and add the output to the question

Comment: Sorry, I have about 200 different echo rows on this page coming from a database, so $row dumps all of those values. However, I updated it with this:    var_dump($row["test".$i."MeterVol"] / $row["test".$i."TesterVol"] );

Comment: So in your `for` loop, there is a `$row` variable, which you're accessing to perform your arithmetic. `var_dump` that `$row`.

Comment: What is the average of NaN and 5? I would say it's undefined, but you might have a definition.

Comment: @Paulpro but that is only one of 8 values, so it factors into the average

Comment: @fubar I updated with the 2 rows that are being accessed in the loop. One is for the 8 meterVolume values and one is for the 8 testerVolume values

Comment: @fubar and as you can see in the screenshot, all 8 fields for GPM, meter volume, tester volume and accuracy are their own <td> cell, but the corrected accuracy from the loop is all on one row, essentially one cell

Comment: @fubar I also added the full table code for context, if it helps

Comment: The question is how does it factor in. The average of NaN, 5, and 7 could be a lot of things. I would say it's undefined, but you might day it's `(0+5+7)/3=4` or `(5+7)/2 = 6`, or something else depending on what you're using it for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work out the average of the 8 values, you need to sum the 8 values and then divide by the number of values, in this case 8.

For example:

```
<?php

$accuracy = [];

for ($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++) {
    $accuracy[] = $row["test{$i}MeterVol"] / $row["test{$i}TesterVol"] * $row["test{$i}Accuracy"] / 100;
}

$average = array_sum($accuracy) / count($accuracy);
```

If you were therefore to store the value of `$testFinalForm` during each iteration of your current loop in an array, as per the above example, you could calculate the sum using `array_sum` and thus the average by using `count` to find the array length.